# System.ServiceModel.FaultException'1' Where might the error be?

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I am calling a function in a wcf service which takes a string (of in-determinant length) as a parameter.  This is a function that I have had working before (but admittedly in a much earlier version of visual studio).

When I now call this in a new version of the program built in vs 2013 using .net4.5.1 I get this ServiceModel faultexception telling me that 'String must be exactly one character long.

I know that the service definition has not changed and is as it was.  However it is no longer possible for me to liase with the people who created it so I cannot quiz them.  I am assuming that there is an error an my end that must be causing this but really don't know enough about this field to make a reasoned educated guess.

So two questions.

Am I right in my assumption that this is probably something wrong at my end?  If not then I Using this service is going to be a waste of time.

If my assumption is correct and somewhere I have made an error where might that be.  Do I for example need to add some extra configuration settings?

IF there is additional info I could provide but haven't please don't hesitate to ask.  As I say this is an area of programing where in truth I'm still learning my way around so instinct suggests I'm at fault I just don't know why.  I'm using similar code to that in a previous version which did work.

I know that I can actively interact with the service because I can pull info from it.  The problem seems to be when sending info up to it.

Thanks

EDIT

this is the function I'm calling that produces the serviceModel exception;

```
Public Function salesXMLCheck(ByVal xmlString As String) As String Implements ErsTestSite.IERSAPIService.salesXMLCheck
            Return MyBase.Channel.salesXMLCheck(xmlString)
        End Function
```

and it's called from here;

```
 Using ters As New ErsTestSite.ERSAPIServiceClient
            ters.Open()
            returnsEditor.Text = ters.salesXMLAdd(submissionsEditor.Text)
            ters.Close()
        End Using
```

this is the config section for the service;

```
<bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
              <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IERSAPIService"
                         maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
               maxBufferSize="20000000"
               maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
                <security mode="None" />
              </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you posted some code.  Also include any relevant config on the client or the service so we can see how your bindings are being set up.

Comment: Hi Mike , thanks for taking a look at this for me, have added some extra detail to the question if it helps.